# Irrlicht engine game wont compile on linux. Undefined refrences(opengl and xfree)

Tags: opengl, linux, irrlicht

I'm trying to port over my game I'm developing to Linux. But when i compile i get a lot of undefined references to mostly functions that look like they belong to OpenGL. Most are titled gl...  But one of them is called XFree.

I compiled it with this command:

```
g++ main.cpp -L../../../LIB/irrlicht-1.8.3/lib/Linux/ -lIrrlicht -I../../../LIB/irrlicht-1.8.3/include/
```

one of the errors:

```
/home/owner/LIB/irrlicht-1.8.3/source/Irrlicht/COpenGLDriver.cpp:3746: undefined reference to `glVertex3f
```

Comment: should be more like: `g++ ... -lGLU -lGL -lX11`

Comment: Which GNU/Linux distro are you trying to port your game to specifically? Are you sure that you have the development packages for those libraries installed? Most distros have a prepackaged version of Irrlicht that is probably a much better idea to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future people running into my problem i found the solution.
I was able to compile my project with this.

-w is for removing warning its optional.
I also found you need to link with -lXxf86vm

```
g++ main.cpp -w -I../../../LIB/irrlicht-1.8.3/include/ -L ../../../LIB/irrlicht-1.8.3/lib/Linux/ -lIrrlicht -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -lXxf86vm
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install development libraries for OpenGL and X11. You didn't state what distro you're using, but in Ubuntu OpenGL development library is in package `libgl1-mesa-dev`.

Comment: I tried it on ubuntu and Debian(laptop). which are pretty similar. But thank you ill try that.